# Is there a way to programatically suppress the jstree "create" event from firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jstree

Here's my dilemma:  I'm using both the contextmenu and programatically creating new jstree nodes.  The problem that I run into is that when I programatically create a new jstree node, it also fires the contextmenu `.create` bind event.

So, in essence, duplication occurs since the manual create call is made as well as the contextmenu create bind.  I partially accounted for this by putting an **if** statement within the contextmenu create event handler to prevent it from running its contents if the event were triggered programatically.

However, duplications still result since that contextmenu bound is always called no matter what.

Is there a way to suppress that contextmenu create event whenever `create` is called programatically?

Here's the code:

The Context menu event handler for "Create":

```
        .bind("create.jstree", function(e, data) {
        debugger;
        // Ajax call to Server with parent node id and new node text
        if($("#RMSDoc_RequirementFlag").val() == "CONTEXT")
        {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": '@Url.Content("~/RMS/insertRMSNode")',
                "data": {
                        "ParentID" : parseInt(ParentNode),
                        "Level" : parseInt(ParentLevel),
                        "ChildNodeText" : data.rslt.obj.text()
                },
                "success": function(new_data) {
//                    $.jstree._reference($("#RequirementsTree")).refresh(-1);
                    var addedNode = data.rslt.obj;

                    $(addedNode).attr("id", "rbs_" + new_data.RMSHierarchyId);
                    $(addedNode).attr("name", "rlevel_" + new_data.Level);
                    $(addedNode).addClass("jstree-closed");
                    ParentNode = null;
                    ParentLevel = null;
                    data = null;
                    return new_data;
                }   
            });
        }

        BranchReqFLag = null;
```

Here is the programatically called `create` method:

```
    function ReqSuccess(response) {
    // Dynamically add tree branch only (for ipad)
    if($("#RMSDoc_RequirementFlag").val() == "ADD_BRANCH_ONLY") {
        $("#RMSDoc_TreeBranch_id").val("0");
        $("#RMSDoc_TreeBranch_Text").val("");
        $("#RequirementsTree").jstree("create", null, "last", {"data" : response.TreeBranch.Text,
                                                                "state" : "closed",
                                                                "attr" : { "id" : "rbs_" + response.TreeBranch.id, "name" : "rlevel_" + response.TreeBranch.Level }
                                                                });
    }
```